# CSS Menu Sub Menu Not Working Correctly

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, menu

I cannot seem to get the sub-menu to appear on this website I built: http://website-test-lab.com/sites/mirandaparsons/

If you use Dev tools/Firebug, and check .sub-menu to display: block; then you can see that the sub-menu does appear, but not in plain sight. I've tried adding z-index to several of the menu areas with no luck.
The odd thing is, that it does appear correctly in FF on Windows?!

I haven't pasted the code here because there would be so much to copy and paste.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you need is a `background-color` to `.sub-menu` and position relative to `.nav` I just tried to set it and you can see the sub menu well :

```
.navigation .nav {
    position:relative;
}
```

PS : Worked on firefox 33 Mac

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your CSS:

```
.navigation .nav {
     position: relative; 
}
```

This would properbly be usefull to read: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add this css to your stylesheet

```
#site-navigation.main-navigation{
position:relative;
}
```